# Not all particle instances rendering

Tags: rendering, particles, hair, instances

I have a tree mesh with the following structure:

• a base mesh ("tree.002") for the trunk and largest branches, with a hair particle system

• a twig mesh ("branchmesh") instanced to the above particle system, with its own hair particle system

• a leaf mesh ("leaf") instanced to the twig's system

This all seems to work out nicely in the viewport, but when I go to render,
many of my leaves are missing (though all the twigs seem to appear).

My leaves have double sided normals and both instance modifiers have "show particles when:" alive, unborn, and dead activated

Below you can see a snapshot of the render with a corresponding section of the viewport that shows just how few of my leaves are rendering.

What am I missing?

[image: Screenshot of missing leaves]